# VMware Virtual Machine - Can I duplicate mouse/keyboard inputs

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware

I'm new to the virtual machines and I would like to learn some info about input broadcasting.

If I have multiple clients active in vmware (multiple vms), can I send my mouse/keyboard actions to all of them at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

In a normal environment, VMware Virtual Machines are independent machines. I have 6 or 7 here on my laptop.

Now in the same normal environment, a mouse and keyboard do not operate 3 or 4 physical computers at the same time.

So same for the virtual machines, that is, a host mouse cannot simultaneously control several virtual machines.

If you are able to broadcast a mouse to several physical machines, then you might be able to do the same for virtual machines.

I am not sure how you might do that, but I am just observing that, in this regard, physical and virtual machines work the same way.